# Update extensions with rte fields and <link>Syntax

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i have to update an extension from TYPO3 6.2 to 9.5. This extension uses three fields with rte which contains links in old syntax: and so on. After running all TYPO3 update scripts the old syntax was not corrected. I changed the TCA of the extension to the new syntax and installed the extension so i can edit all entries in the backend. It seems that most is working correctly now but not the old internal links. In the database they are in the old syntax  so the links vanish in the RTE in backend. I tried to rerun the update script but this doesn't change it. How can i trick the the updater to convert the fields of my extension?

Thanks!